# Why my input bar stuck on the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want my input box to be on the center of the page like a sign in page but it keep stucking on the left top of the page. I have tried using align-items-center, mx-auto, etc. but it doesn't work.

```css
.signin {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.signin input {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.input-group-text {
  width: 90px;
}

.container-fluid {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid flex-column justify-content-center mx-auto">
  <div class="input-group signin email">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">Email</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" aria-label="Enter your email" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group signin password">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">Password</div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" aria-label="Enter your password" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the main issue is that you span the entire with so mx-auto has no effect. Next issue is, that your element is to small to cover the page. Your elements height is set to fit-content and as such you cannot vertical center as the height is not larger as the content.

Comment: so, i assume that i need to set the height and width of the input box? sorry i dont really understand @tacoshy

Comment: no within the container and I highly advice you to use the `label` tag instead of a div to label your inputs. Thats what you have labels for. Those semantic tags are also very important for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `.container-fluid` the following styles and it will bring your input fields to the center of the page.

```
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```